# How to properly configure the local network for the correct operation of iptv?

Tags: router, switch, local, iptv

There is a local network. A switch is connected to the main router on port 3, which distributes the Internet to a TV, ps4 and a TV set-top box. For the television to work correctly, you need to configure port 3 as iptv, but then other devices connected to the switch go to a completely different network. How to properly configure the connection to see the TV on the LAN and iptv worked correctly?

The switch is used the most common, there is still a second router at my disposal (you can use it instead of a smart switch)

Comment: The router might simply not support mixing IPTV and regular internet. I once had that setup (Deutsche Telekom Entertain), it used multicast and IGMP to “turn on and off” IPTV (in a single local network). On the uplink, there were two different VLANs over ATM (VDSL).

Comment: @DanielB, I have a second router that I tried to connect instead of a switch and configure iptv there. But even this does not work...

Comment: Why is the "completely different network" bad? What IP scheme (192.168.0.1, etc) does it end up on and how is that different from normal? It sounds like you *are* setting it up properly for IPTV considering that's how you know how to set up your devices. It sounds like you need to describe more about what is and isn't working and how.

Comment: @Mokubai, The fact is that this network is given an ip from the provider and it changes every time. That is, I can’t configure constant access to it from the main LAN in any way.

Comment: I see, rereading your question again it sounds like you are going to have to split the IPTV output from your main network. You need to run a separate cable/switch on port 3 for the IPTV network, and put the "main" network switch on another port.

Comment: @Mokubai, It's a shame ... there is simply no way to separate another wire for the TV and ps4

Answer (score 0):

Since your (or rather your provider’s) IPTV setup seems to be somewhat lacking in sophistication, you probably won’t be able to have all devices in a single network. That means features like remote control apps will probably not work. You indicate that running another cable is not possible.

(Below, I assume that it’s your set-top box that requires IPTV access.)

There is a standardized way to run multiple networks over a single Ethernet link: 802.1Q VLAN Tagging. It requires boxes on both ends that understand 802.1Q. So-called “managed switches” usually support it. With these, you create the following setup:

```
+----------+              +----------+
|  Router  |              | Switch 1 |
|          |              |          |
|   Port 1 +--Normal LAN--+ P2    P1 +--+
|   Port 2 +---IPTV LAN---+ P3       |  |
+----------+              +----------+  |
                                        |
  +------Existing cable to TV area------+
  |  
  |  +----------+
  |  | Switch 2 |
  |  |          |
  +--+ P1    P2 +--To set-top box
     |       P3 +--To TV
     |       P4 +--To PS4
     +----------+
```

Where 2 VLANs are defined and assigned to ports as follows:

- VLAN 1 (normal LAN):

  - Switch 1 Port 1 (Tagged)
  - Switch 1 Port 2 (Untagged)
  - Switch 2 Port 1 (Tagged)
  - Switch 2 Ports 3 & 4 (Untagged)
- VLAN 2 (IPTV):

  - Switch 1 Port 1 (Tagged)
  - Switch 1 Port 3 (Untagged)
  - Switch 2 Port 1 (Tagged)
  - Switch 2 Port 2 (Untagged)

The switches you need are called “managed switches”. In theory, even the most basic ones (≤30 €) should do. For example, the TP-Link TL-SG105E has all the required features. I do not know about its reliability and performance though.

In general, all consumer routers have the required hardware capabilities. The software won’t expose these, unfortunately. Using OpenWrt (or the like), you can tap into that potential—if alternate firmware is available for your device.